# Создание HTML таблички

Tags: php, логика

```
do {
        $result3 = mysql_query("",$db);
        $b = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
        echo "<th>".$a['dateof']."</th>";
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        echo "<td>".$b['mark']."</td>";
}
while(); 
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">predmet </th>
<th>2016-05-19</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<th>2016-05-20</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

не могу понять как в цикле делать таблицу вот такую:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th rowspan="2">predm</th>
     <th>20.05.16</th>
     <th>21.05.16</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>4</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

вот грубый код того что надо:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Lessons WHERE subjectId='$subj' AND kyrs='$kyrs' AND semester='$semestr' AND groupid='$user[groupn]'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query, $db);
    echo "<th rowspan='2'>".$Subject['Name']."</th>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
        $a = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        do {
            echo "<th>".$a['dateof']."</th>";
        }
        while($a = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Lessons WHERE subjectId='$subj' AND kyrs='$kyrs' AND semester='$semestr' AND groupid='$user[groupn]'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query, $db);
$a = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
            do {
                $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Marks WHERE lessonid='$a[id]' AND studentid='$_SESSION[id]'",$db);
                $b = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
                echo "<td>".$b['mark']."</td>";
            }
            while($a = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
        }
        else {
            echo "нет инфы по предмету.";
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: не совсем ясно , а для чего табличку в цикле выводить ? обычно новости или изображения , а табличку для чего ?

Comment: у меня таблица по уроку  его дате проведения и отметка по той дате

Comment: абсолютно чудовищное применение PHP, вас так где-то учат или вы сами по статьям и книжкам?

Comment: самоучка 
а поконкретней что не так

Comment: mysql драйвер удален, проснитесь. 2016 год.